# Responsive layout, desktop mobile

Tags: html, css

Please, can somebody help me to implement this responsive layout? I tried but couldn't do. Thank you a lot.
Desktop and mobile version.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAq5L.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAGJV.png

Comment: Have you made any attempt to achieve the goal yet? You would try to achieve that by using background-image: linear-gradient with different angles, defined on ::before and ::after selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
<div class="purple-triangle">
</div>

<div class="black-triangle"></div>

<div class="text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tellus felis, suscipit ac justo eu, dignissim euismod elit. Aenean eros enim, ornare sit amet vehicula quis, auctor vitae felis. Maecenas eu auctor purus. Donec eget mauris a diam tempus volutpat. In sed ornare neque. Praesent laoreet blandit justo porta hendrerit. Proin vel magna ac nisi condimentum rhoncus eu in est. Aliquam erat volutpat. 

</p></div>

  .black-triangle{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
 width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 50% solid transparent;
  border-right: 50vw solid transparent;

  border-bottom: 100vh solid black;
}

.purple-triangle{
  position: absolute;
  top:-50px;
  left:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
 width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 50% solid transparent;
  border-right: 100vw solid transparent;

  border-top: 100vh solid purple;
}

.text{
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 20vh;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
```

Comment: hi, no its not responsive, as i already commented below 
" the problem is not with clip-path property, the problem with positioning, I can't make those 2 layouts responsive. On small screens i need 2 triangles separated by text, and on large devices, the purple triangle should be placed above the black one, and text should be placed on the right side, if you can help that would be awesome, thanks"
Sorry if its badly explained

Comment: I think I understand you :) You want to use css media queries. check out this example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OqNjxy. It uses media queries for max-width: 768px. So you need to specify every breakpoint you want to use. It can become very confusing for large webpages, so instead I would recommend using a framework, like bootstrap.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something like this on mobile or tab screen**

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vti1y.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this easiest solution on the internet for making polygon shapes
You can use a CSS property clip_path to produce a shape of any type.

> -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0%, 50% 100%, 0 100%); This line represents that we are drawing polygon which has three points and
>   specifying the location of each point in terms of x and y. You can
>   specify the position in terms of px, % or any unit terminology

And Similarly,

> -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 20%,0 85%); This line represents that we are drawing polygon which has four points.

```
#CSS CODE
*{
  padidng:0;
  margin:0;
}
#first{
background-color:purple;
height:350px;
width:100%;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 20%,0 85%);
} 
#last{
  position:relative;
  top:-200px;
  background-color: black;
height:350px;
width:100%;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0%, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

And HTML Code

```
#HTML CODE
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="first">
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div id="last">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And check this link, where I've written some code just to illustrate the clip-path functionality, and produce the output you have shown in the picture, to jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/awq1mL35/19/

And You can use the same `clip_path` property to produce the same output for mobile using Media Queries

let me know if u didn't understand anything. I'll be more than happy to help you.

Comment: hi, the problem is not with clip-path property, the problem with positioning, I can't make those 2 layouts responsive. On small screens i need 2 triangles separated by text, and on large devices, the purple triangle should be placed above the black one, and text should be placed on the right side, if you can help that would be awesome, thanks.

Comment: what you can do in this case is to re-write code for both divs in the media_query